# OpenCV setNumThreads Issue

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to enable code paralelization on OpenCV 2.4.8 and for some reason it is not working. I've already built openCV with `WITH_TBB = ON` and `WITH_OPENMP = ON` but for some reason OpenCV is still not adding any boost to my processing procedures.

Does anyone here knows what's going on?

**Update**

```
 int main() {

InitCounter();
vector< vector<Point> > _contours;
vector<Vec4i> _storage;
vector<Vec3f> circles;

VideoCapture capture("30-1.avi");
ofstream fout("data.txt"); 

if(!capture.isOpened()) 
return -1;

//time_t start, end;
int counter=0;
int frameCounter=0;
int frameno=0;

//clock_t startTime = clock();

//time(&start);

for(;;)
{

    Mat frame, finalFrame;
    capture >> frame; 

    // double start=CLOCK2();

    finalFrame = frame;

    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    GaussianBlur(frame, frame, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    threshold(frame, frame, 20, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    dilate(frame, frame, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
    erode(frame, frame, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);

    Canny(frame, frame, 20, 20*2, 3 );

    //double dur = CLOCK2()-start;
    //printf("avg time per frame %f ms. fps %f. frameno = %d\n",avgdur(dur),avgfps(),frameno++ );

    //time(&end);
    //++counter;
    //double sec=difftime(end,start);
    //double fps=counter/sec;
    //cout<<fps<<endl;
    //fout << fps<<"\n";
    //frameCounter++;


    vector<Vec3f> circles;

    findContours(frame,_contours,_storage,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( _contours.size() );
    vector<Rect> boundRect( _contours.size() );
    vector<Point2f>center( _contours.size() );
    vector<float>radius( _contours.size() );

    int temp = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < _contours.size(); i++ )
    { 
        if( _contours[i].size() > 100 )
        {
           approxPolyDP( Mat(_contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
           boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(_contours[i]) );
           minEnclosingCircle( (Mat)_contours[i], center[i], radius[i] );
           temp = i;
           break;
        }
    }

    //Scalar color2 = Scalar( 0, 0,255 );
    //rectangle( finalFrame, boundRect[temp].tl(), boundRect[temp].br(), color2, 2, 7, 0 );

    //fout << avgdur(dur)<<"\n"; 
    //frameCounter++;

    //if(frameCounter == 3600)
    //break;

    //imshow("frame", finalFrame);
    if(waitKey(1000/120) >= 0) break;
    //waitKey(1000/120);
}

 //clock_t ends = clock();
 //cout << "Running Time : " << (double) (ends - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

system("pause");
 }
```

Comment: Try to enable openMP in compiler options of your project. And take a look at CPU cores loading in task manager.

Comment: Adrey Smorodov. I've checked the task manager and it shows me only one thread created to my project. I've enabled the openMP compiler options enabling openMP. Do you have any idea whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this code (append  it (the main body) to the beginning of your program) :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

#ifdef _OPENMP
    printf("OpenMP is supported. Supported version is: %4.2f\n",_OPENMP/100.0);

    int N_PROC = omp_get_num_procs(); // Number of available processors
    printf("Number of available processors: %d\n",N_PROC);

    int MAX_THREADS = omp_get_max_threads(); // Numbers of available threads
    printf("Numbers of available threads: %d\n",MAX_THREADS);

#else
    printf("OpenMP is not supported.");
#endif

 getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

What does it print?

UPD: Example of parallelization by hand:

```
void NEDI(Mat& src,Mat &dst,int ZK=1,int MT=6,int ML=3,double BT=16,int BS=16,int SZ=8)
{
    if(src.channels()>1)
    {
        vector<Mat> src_arr;
        cv::split(src,src_arr);
        Mat tmp;
        // If openmp supported, then go parallel
#ifdef _OPENMP
        // Thread number
        omp_set_num_threads(3);
#pragma omp parallel shared(src_arr) private(tmp)
        {       
            int n=omp_get_thread_num(); // Get number of current thread
            Nedi_1_Channel(src_arr[n],tmp,ZK,MT,ML,BT,BS,SZ); // Process data for current thread
            tmp.copyTo(src_arr[n]);
        }       
#else
        Nedi_1_Channel(src_arr[0],tmp,ZK,MT,ML,BT,BS,SZ);
        tmp.copyTo(src_arr[0]);

        Nedi_1_Channel(src_arr[1],tmp,ZK,MT,ML,BT,BS,SZ);
        tmp.copyTo(src_arr[1]);

        Nedi_1_Channel(src_arr[2],tmp,ZK,MT,ML,BT,BS,SZ);
        tmp.copyTo(src_arr[2]);
#endif

        cv::merge(src_arr,dst);
    }else
    {
        Nedi_1_Channel(src,dst,ZK,MT,ML,BT,BS,SZ);
    }
}
```

Comment: The output of the program is: `OpenMP is supported. Supported version is: 2002.03  - Number of available processor: 8 - Number of avaiilable threads: 8.`  So, why it is just creating 1 thread? Do u want to see my code?

Comment: Ok, I see, I think the problem is that you use opencv functions that does not using openmp intensively in their implementations. I think, that it will be more useful to turn on SSE instruction set (it can add some perfomance). Or parallelize you processing by hands (process several frames simultaneously for example). But it need some undestanding of openmp directives. You can find good tutorials in the web. Take a look here: http://openmp.org/wp/resources/#Tutorials

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrey. I've already tried to query multiple frames without success. Do you know any good way to do it with openMP?

Comment: You can try first read number of frames (equal to number of supported threads). The speed of this operation is bounded by speed of hard disk transactions. Then you have 8 (for your case) frames of video sequence. You can set 8 separate threads, one per each frame. It should work. But it depends on correct usage of variables visibility (local, global, etc. see openmp manual for description). You should properly share variables between threads.

Comment: I've updated my answer, with example of that I mean. It process the 3 channel image by channels. Each thread process one channel.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply again. I just have a last question. How to query a specific frame from `VideoCapture`. I want to devide the total number of frames to the 8 threads, creating ranges of frames for each thread. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Just read 8 frames one by one before you begin processing. It'll be faster than random access to frames. Then process 8 frames in parallel. Next cycle read next 8 frames and so on.

Comment: Oh! this is a great way to solve the problem! Thanks for ur reply!